# How to link a NotMapped property manually as entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have two classes:

```
public partial class Registry
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public partial class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TitleSearch { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to fill `Registry.Category` with the first category which `Registry.Title` contains `Category.SearchTitle`, using the `Like` operator. 
It´s possible to make this link automatically when I call `Registry.Category`, and see if a category is not null?

I want to make this:

```
    if(registry.Category != null){
    categoryName = registry.Category.Name;
    }
```

**Updated**
I tried this, and it worked:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Category Category { 
    get
    {
    Context db = new Context();
    var category = db.Categories.Where(e=> Title.Contains(e.TitleSearch)).FirstOrDefault();
    return category;
    }
    }
```

Comment: via mappings, not likely since there is no direct relationships between Registry and Category. In cases like these I would consider treating the Categories list as a lookup where a Registry pattern class can be responsible for retrieving the complete list of categories and caching them. Then the Registry entity Category property can just consult the CategoryRegistry. The Category property on Registry does not need to be virtual when NotMapped is used.

Comment: @StevePy Thank you. But, what about call the context directly in the class `Registry` and use it only if I get the property `Category`. I will try that.